# Apache Virtual Hosts Both Going to Same Location

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

So I just purchased a second domain that I want to serve on the same Apache server as my main domain.  However after updating the virtual hosts, both domains are still going to the first entry.  Both entries work correctly, if I switch the order whichever is first will be honored.  What am I missing?

Here is the config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost *:83
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
        ServerName www.mainsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/path/path2/path3
    ServerName www.seccondarysite.cc
</VirtualHost>
```

For reference I am running:

Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding also `ServerAlias` to catch all the variations. e.g.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/path/path2/path3
     ServerName seccondarysite.cc
     ServerAlias *.secondarysite.cc
</VirtualHost>
```

This will allow to reach the same site with both www, asd, whatever other prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to remove the www. from the server names.  All is working correctly now.